# Lsqnonlin wrong f(x) value

Tags: matlab, optimization

I need to solve the inverse problem and I use lsqnonlin to optimize my parameters. In some cases, lsqnonlin works incorrectly. To demonstrate the problem I have two variants of simple code. First works well, second doesn't work at all.

1. In the first variant, I optimize x^2.

   ```
   options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter');
   param_opt = lsqnonlin(@(param)loss_func(param),0.1,-1,1,options);

   function loss = loss_func(param)
      loss = param.^2;
   end
   ```

   I get this result:

   ```
                                           Norm of      First-order 
   Iteration  Func-count     f(x)          step          optimality
       0          2          0.0001                        0.0022
       1          4     7.40992e-06      0.0456004       0.000299      
       2          6     5.09591e-07      0.0248167       3.92e-05      
       3          8     3.35176e-08      0.0130147       5.02e-06
   ```

   param_opt = 0.0135;
2. In the second variant, I add a small error to the loss function (as I have in my real experiment) and lsqnonlin doesn't work.

   ```
   options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter');
   param_opt = lsqnonlin(@(param)loss_func(param),0.1,-1,1,options);
   function loss = loss_func(param)
      loss = param.^2+(1e-6)*rand;
   end
   ```

   I get this result:

   ```
                                           Norm of      First-order 
   Iteration  Func-count     f(x)          step          optimality
       0          2     0.000100005                        0.0315
       1          4     0.000100005     0.00299768         0.0315      
       2          6     0.000100005     0.00074942         0.0315      
       3          8     0.000100005    0.000187355         0.0315      
       4         10     0.000100005    4.68387e-05         0.0315      
       5         12     0.000100005    1.17097e-05         0.0315      
       6         14     0.000100005    2.92742e-06         0.0315      
       7         16     0.000100005    7.31855e-07         0.0315
   ```

   param_opt = 0.1000;

What am I doing wrong? The problem that I have in my real experiment is that f(x) from lsqnonlin doesn't match with the real loss_func output.

Comment: You say it's working in the first case, but IMO right answer is 0.

Comment: Beware that in the second case, loss function is changing every call (rand is called each call). Place the random error value outside the loss function to keep it constant through all optim iterations.

Comment: Right answer is 0, but the result depends on default criteria of exit. I understand that loss function changes at every iteration, but I don't understand why lsqnonlin returns f(x) value that is not equal to real loss function output (I checked it in debug mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to lsqnonlin should be a vector `loss = param`, the algorithm will do the sum of squares. Anyway here i think that you better use fmincon:

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter');
x = fmincon(@loss_func,0.1,[],[],[],[],-1,1,[],options);
function loss = loss_func(param)
   loss = param.^2;
end
```